# Converting result set to a dict with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to convert the result set of parsing to a dict with pyparsing. But dictionary contains only the last member of result set, not all of them. What am i missing?

Here's my code:

```
from pyparsing import *

test = """
pci24 u2480-L0
fcs1 g4045-L1
pci25 h6045-L0
en192 v7024-L3
pci26 h6045-L1
"""

grammar_pci = Combine("pci" + Word( nums )).setResultsName("name") + Word( alphanums + "-" ).setResultsName("loc")
grammar_non_pci = Suppress( Regex( r"(?!pci).*" ) )

grammar = OneOrMore( Group(grammar_pci).setResultsName("pci_slots") | grammar_non_pci, stopOn=StringEnd())

def main():
  data = grammar.parse_string(test, parseAll=True)
  print(data)
  data_dict = data.as_dict()
  print(data_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the outputs of data and data_dict:

```
[['pci24', 'u2480-L0'], ['pci25', 'h6045-L0'], ['pci26', 'h6045-L1']]
{'pci_slots': {'name': 'pci26', 'loc': 'h6045-L1'}}
```

pyparsing version: 3.0.9

Comment: Good use of results names. To gather multiple results this way, add `listAllMatches=True` in your call to setResultsName.  See docs here: https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html#pyparsing.ParserElement.set_results_name

Answer (score 2):

I hope, this will fix the issue (set listAllMatches=True in setResultName of 'pci_slots')

```
from pyparsing import *

test = """
pci24 u2480-L0
fcs1 g4045-L1
pci25 h6045-L0
en192 v7024-L3
pci26 h6045-L1
"""

grammar_pci = Combine("pci" + Word( nums )).setResultsName("name") + Word( alphanums + "-" ).setResultsName("loc")
grammar_non_pci = Suppress( Regex( r"(?!pci).*" ) )

grammar = OneOrMore( Group(grammar_pci).setResultsName("pci_slots", listAllMatches=True) | grammar_non_pci, stopOn=StringEnd())


data = grammar.parse_string(test, parseAll=True)
print(data)
data_dict = data.as_dict()
print(data_dict)
```

Comment: Please don't just give code as an answer. Even though it may solve the issue in OP's question, elaborate a bit on your changes and explain why this should work

Comment: data return a list of list, so you have to loop through it to convert it into a dictionary. By default it will take the last item.

Comment: The output has changed, but "pci_slots" container has vanished. Here is the output:
[{'name': 'pci24', 'loc': 'u2480-L0'}, {'name': 'pci25', 'loc': 'h6045-L0'}, {'name': 'pci26', 'loc': 'h6045-L1'}]

I think there is something has to be known about as_dict. If we traverse the list manually, the dictionary tree gets damaged.

Comment: It doesn't really get damaged, you just lose the key-value associations because you are exporting a separate list of dicts. See my comment above about using `listAllMatches=True` to build a result with all the groups, not just the last one.

Comment: Yes, OneOrMore( Group(grammar_pci).setResultsName("pci_slots", listAllMatches=True) fix the issue and it is the preferred approach (also it will give you the same result {'pci_slots': [a.as_dict() for a in data]})

Comment: @MuhammadAli if you update your answer including Paul's "listAllMatches=True" suggestion, i'll mark your answer as the accepted answer. Thank you guys, you helped so much.

Comment: @MuhammadAli - Thanks for pitching in on this pyparsing question, I'm always glad to see others helping out with this library.